# Pull dmidecode info over SSH and save info to local file with hostname entry

Tags: ssh, bash-scripting, remote, remote-execution, pull

Scripting is not my strong suite, but I'm trying to learn.

Trying to pull dmidecode info, specifically 'Product' from the dmidecode output, on remote systems from the main server, and save the info into a local file on the server with each entry noted by the remote hostname being accessed via SSH.

This is what I have so far in my script:

```
for i in `{cat /home/file_with_hostnames}`; do ssh $i "dmidecode | grep Prod"; done
```

When I run the above, I get an output looking like this for each entry in 'file_with_hostnames' on the servers stdout:

```
Product Name: Elo AiO

Product Name: Elo AiO

Product Name: Elo AiO
```

However, each entry is not noted with the hostname being connected to, which is read from the file /home/file_with_hostnames. I would like the info that I pull to be stored in a file with each computer name being connected to, running the dmidecode | grep Prod command.

For example, I would like the info to look something like this:

```
PC1 - Product Name: Elo AiO

PC2 - Product Name: Elo AiO
```

etc... as indicated by the /home/file_with_hostnames file.

Timestamps are not that vital, but if they could be included as well, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the "Wonderful World of Scripting".

The quickest answer is to echo the output of hostname, date and dmidecode from the string you pass to ssh:

```
for i in `{cat /home/file_with_hostnames}`; do ssh $i "echo "`hostname` `date` `dmidecode | grep Prod`" "; done
```

- You could use some other character between the commands, such as semi-colon, to help parse the output
- I was surprised that it obeys the order of the inner and outer pair of double-quotes ( `"` ), normally constructs like this need the inner pair of double-quotes to be escaped ( `\"` ).

I'm not sure why you use `{...}` around the `cat` command, when I tried that format (always willing to find out new things) it returned `-bash: {cat: command not found`, then I realised I had assumed you are using Bash, that is my bad and my suggestions, below, may not work, sorry.

Some things that might make your life easier:

- The newer method of executing commands using the `$( ... )` format instead of backticks is, in my opinion, easier and it allows nesting. The spaces before and after the command string are just my personal preference
- Use `-q` with `ssh`, this means "quiet" and stops any banners displaying, it's not necessary but helps to keep output easier to read
- `dmidecode` takes arguments that will output specific information, which avoids getting `Prod` lines from other hardware (like I did when testing): `dmidecode --string system-product-name`, the man page shows other strings you can use
- Another personal preference, I always use `-i` with the `grep` command (and `egrep`, `fgrep`, etc.) to make the match case-insensitive, just means I don't need to know the case beforehand

So taking into account the above:

```
for i in $( cat /home/file_with_hostnames ); do ssh -q $i "echo "$( hostname ) $( date ) $( dmidecode --string system-product-name )" "; done
```

I hope this helps, if I've got things wrong, please be gentle with me, this is my first proper posting,

Nick

P.S. My old eyes read the year of your post as 2023, I now realise it's nearly a year old and you've probably moved on from this and have a lot more scripting experience under your belt.
Sigh, just when I though I'd found a new post that I could *actually* answer :)
I'll leave this here in the hope it helps others.